How can I infer the generic type parameters of a generic parameter in typescript?
I have a type that represents an operation in my application:
type Operation<A, B> = {
    execute: (data: A) => B;
};

An operation looks like this:
const op = {
    execute: (data: string) => {
        return data;
    },
};

I'm trying to create an abstraction that lets me decorate this operation. Adding a decoration should preserve any previously added fields. So for example when I want to augment an operation with transaction handling:
export const wrapInTransaction = <A, B, O extends Operation<A, B>>(
   { execute, ...rest}: O 
): O => {
    const wrappedExecute = (data: A) =>
    {
        // add transaction logic here
        return execute(data)
    }        
    return {
        ...rest,
        execute: wrappedExecute,
    } as O;
}

I'm accepting a subtype of Operation, not a generic Operation<A, B>. My problem is that this doesn't work:
const wrapped = wrapInTransaction(op);

// Argument of type '{ execute: (data: string) => string; }' is not assignable to parameter // of type 'Operation<unknown, unknown>'.
//   Types of property 'execute' are incompatible.
//     Type '(data: string) => string' is not assignable to type '(data: unknown) => unknown'.
//       Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
//         Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'

as the type of O is not inferred. Can I somehow construct a default value for O that infers A and B?

Constraints like O extends Operation<A, B> aren't inference sites, see ms/TS#7234. The supported approach is to use an intersection as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer (or find a duplicate). If not, what's missing?

I see. This seems to work but I'm not sure why. What's & O doing there and how does it get its value? When you return O why do I see the Operation<A, B> too, not just O?

I linked to ms/TS#7234, which describes the intersection approach. See the linked q/a above for more information.

Oh I see, I missed it,  thanks!

I would recommend simplifying the generic. Given that it only applies O to the parameters { execute, ...rest}: O, it can only infer O. While deducing A and B is trivial for humans, we can do it rigorously using the infer keyword documented here: Conditional Types, to help us obtain A and B. Note that it cannot actually be in the generic, otherwise it is a circular type dependency.
// VV this works as well
// type DataFromOperation<T> = T extends Operation<infer A, unknown> ? A : unknown
type DataFromOperation<T extends Operation<unknown, unknown>> = T extends Operation<infer A, unknown> ? A : unknown

export const wrapInTransaction = <O extends Operation<any, any>>(
   { execute, ...rest}: O 
): O => {
    const wrappedExecute = (data: DataFromOperation<O>) =>
    {
        // add transaction logic here
        return execute(data)
    }        
    return {
        ...rest,
        execute: wrappedExecute,
    } as O;
}

View on TS Playground
P.S. I didn't refresh the page before @jcalz answer, which is also perfectly valid and maybe even preferable, dependent on specific requirements (ie. whether you need to keep A, B and O as generic parameters).
